# Is 'Protection' an acceptable Java class name

Tags: java, coding-style, code-quality

This comes from a closed thread at [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397519/is-protection-an-acceptable-java-class-name), where there are already some useful answers, though a commenter suggested I post here.  I hope this is ok!

I'm trying my best to write good readable, code, but often have doubts in my work!

I'm creating some code to check the status of some protected software, and have created a class which has methods to check whether the software in use is licensed (there is a separate Licensing class).

I've named the class 'Protection', which is currently accessed, via the creation of an appProtect object. The methods in the class allow to check a number of things about the application, in order to confirm that it is in fact licensed for use.

Is 'Protection' an acceptable name for such a class?

I read somewhere that if you have to think to long in names of methods, classes, objects etc, then perhaps you may not be coding in an Object Oriented way. I've spent a lot of time thinking about this before making this post, which has lead me to doubt the suitability of the name!

In creating (and proof reading) this post, I'm starting to seriously doubt my work so far. I'm also thinking I should probably rename the object to applicationProtection rather than appProtect (though am open to any comments on this too?). I'm posting non the less, in the hope that I'll learn something from others views/opinions, even if they're simply confirming I've "done it wrong"!

EDIT:

Thanks for all the responses, which have been all been helpful.  I think 'Protector' fits the bill perfectly, as the class checks the license, and acts accordingly.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more about what this class does, but is it possible that "Protector" would be a better name?

Comment: Thank you.  That's exactly what I was looking for!  I'll get the hang of this soon...

Answer (score 5):

I think you might be overanalyzing this. Be wary of analysis paralysis.

So I suggest you stick with the name for now. You can always change it later. Besides, most entities tends to change name a couple of times while developing, so you don't need to worry.

Comment: +1.  Also avoid duplicating the package name in the class name.

Comment: I am very aware of analysis paralysis, and it's constant attempts to get in my way.  Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

The noun you use to name an object usually comes out of what that object represents. What the object represents is a function of its member variables and its methods. So, what are they? :-)

Answer (score 0):

`Protection` is too generic ( protection from what? ).

I would try to use a more specific name. Its very hard to say what the name of the class is without knowing what it is intended for. If it is checking a licence, you can use `LicenseChecker`.

I prefer having real nouns as Class names. There is lot of debate on this so I won't claim I'm 100% right - it is just my preference. Although LicenseChecker is a noun, it feels wrong to me - because it is still emphasizes on the verb ( check ).  What I would have is a `License` object with a `isValid()` method which checks whether license is valid. Your `License` object can be obtained from your `Licensing` class, using `Licensing.getLicense()`

Comment: Thank you.  Not wanting to be pedantic, but I read that you shouldn't use the object name in a method name, which in your above suggestion would change `Licensing.getLicense()` to `Licensing.get()`.  Can I ask on your opinion of this?  I understand the reasoning behind not repeeating object names, but just using 'get()' seems too non-descriptive to me.    Source: point 12 of [Java Programming Style Guidelines](http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html#Naming%20Conventions)

Comment: My interpretation of the `Licensing` class was that it provides/creates/manages licences but is not the licence itself. That's why it got a instance of `License` using `getLicense()`. The link you gave is for object properties. For example, if you have a `License` object, and want to get expiry date, you should do `License.getExpiry()` instead of `License.getLicenseExpiry()`. If `Licensing` class describes **one** license, then there is no need to do another `Licensing.get()`. Just use Licensing class itself. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score -1):

Your class looks like a Singleton Pattern, so SingleLicence.class may interest you